# How to create a query by using a substring of a field as argument?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to create a selection in SQL Server where the zipcodes are between 3000 and 3100. The zipcodes are with numeric and alfanumeric values.

How can you create a select statement like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE SUBSTRING(A.Zipcode, 1, 4) as integer is between 3000 and 3100
```

Comment: i think you want `CAST` or `CONVERT`, not `as integer`.

Comment: `WHERE CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(A.Zipcode,1,4)) BETWEEN 3000 and 3100`

Comment: In SQL, int as just a short form for integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(A.Zipcode, 1, 4) AS INT) BETWEEN 3000
        AND 3100
```

FuzzyTree's comment using CONVERT will work too. CAST and CONVERT perform very similar functions, but CONVERT offers a more flexible output.